# centering all lines of caption such that they have same length as the first

Tags: tikz-pgf

Please see below my code

```tex
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{%
\tikzstyle{every node}=[circle, draw, fill=black!100,
                       inner sep=0pt, minimum width=5pt]
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=0.8]%
%1st column
\draw(0,0)node[label={[yshift=-0.4cm, xshift=0.1cm]90:{}}](1){};
\draw(0,5)node[label={[yshift=0.4cm, xshift=0.1cm]270:{}}](2){};
\draw(5,5)node[label={[yshift=-0.4cm, xshift=-0.1cm]90:{}}](3){};
\draw(5,0)node[label={[yshift=-0.9cm, xshift=-0.9cm]:{}}](4){};

%1st column
\draw(1)--(2);
\draw(2)--(3);
\draw(3)--(4);
\draw(4)--(1);
\end{tikzpicture}
}\captionsetup{justification=centering}
{\captionof{figure}{This figure shows a cycle of length $4$.
\\Note: I need to make a note here. Thus, this is a very very very long caption. However, it looks weird being center-justified as the sentences differ in length especiallyWhenThereAreLongWords like this. How can I make it center-justified and all lines have an equal length with the first line.}}
```

I attached the current output. Can we code it like desired caption 1 or 2? Thank you!!

[image: current output]

[image: desiredcaption1]

[image: desiredcaption2]

Comment: I cant seem to attach the images. Why is this so? How can i attach a pdf please?

Comment: I have suggested an edit on the question to show the images. That's the problem of markdown arangement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

(red lines indicate text area left and right border)

For such caption and node formation, you need to measure caption width and than setup caption width:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}  % new
\newsavebox\capbox
\newlength\capwidth
\usepackage{tikz}     % new
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}   % new

%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
box/.style = {regular polygon, regular polygon sides=4,
              draw, minimum size=5cm},
dot/.style = {circle, fill, 
              inner sep=0pt, minimum size=4pt}
                    ]
\node (box) [box]   {};
\foreach \i in {1,2,3,4} 
    \node[dot] at (box.corner \i) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
    \savebox\capbox{This figure shows a cycle of length $4$.}
    \setlength\capwidth{\dimexpr\wd\capbox+4em}
    \captionsetup{width=\capwidth}
\caption{\usebox{\capbox}}
\caption*{Note: I need to make a note here. Thus, this is a very very very long caption. However, it looks weird being center-justified as the sentences differ in length especiallyWhenThereAreLongWords like this. How can I make it center-justified and all lines have an equal length with the first line.}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, I change a way how is drawn your square.

**Addendum (1):**

I can't figured out what is the problem at your "send" example. From showed image follows, that you don't need to do anything special:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}  
\usepackage{tikz}     
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}   % new

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
box/.style = {regular polygon, regular polygon sides=4,
              draw, minimum size=5cm},
dot/.style = {circle, fill,
              inner sep=0pt, minimum size=4pt}
                    ]
\node (box) [box]   {};
\foreach \i in {1,2,3,4}
    \node[dot] at (box.corner \i) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{This figure shows a cycle of length $4$.}
\caption*{Note: I need to make a note here. Thus, this is a very very very long caption. However, it looks weird being center-justified as the sentences differ in length especiallyWhenThereAreLongWords like this. How can I make it center-justified and all lines have an equal length with the first line.}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum (2):**

I guess now that you like to have centered caption if it is single line, but in multiline case should be centered only the last text line in caption. If I'm correct, than in preamble loading of `caption` package as is bot above examples with:

```
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[justification=centerlast]{caption}
```

Than the following MWE, in which are now both cases of desired captions' formatting is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}  % new
\usepackage[justification=centerlast]{caption}  % Changed
\newsavebox\capbox
\newlength\capwidth
\usepackage{tikz}     
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}  

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
box/.style = {regular polygon, regular polygon sides=4,
              draw, minimum size=5cm},
dot/.style = {circle, fill,
              inner sep=0pt, minimum size=4pt}
                    ]
\node (box) [box]   {};
\foreach \i in {1,2,3,4}
    \node[dot] at (box.corner \i) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
    \savebox\capbox{This figure shows a cycle of length $4$.}
    \setlength\capwidth{\dimexpr\wd\capbox+4em}
    \captionsetup{width=\capwidth}
\caption{\usebox{\capbox}}
\caption*{Note: I need to make a note here. Thus, this is a very very very long caption. However, it looks weird being center-justified as the sentences differ in length especiallyWhenThereAreLongWords like this. How can I make it center-justified and all lines have an equal length with the first line.}
    \end{figure}
   \begin{figure}
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
box/.style = {regular polygon, regular polygon sides=4,
              draw, minimum size=5cm},
dot/.style = {circle, fill,
              inner sep=0pt, minimum size=4pt}
                    ]
\node (box) [box]   {};
\foreach \i in {1,2,3,4}
    \node[dot] at (box.corner \i) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{This figure shows a cycle of length $4$.}
\caption*{Note: I need to make a note here. Thus, this is a very very very long caption. However, it looks weird being center-justified as the sentences differ in length especiallyWhenThereAreLongWords like this. How can I make it center-justified and all lines have an equal length with the first line.}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Zarko, you are good. This is the first version right? Can you show me the second version too please? Thank you

Comment: @SphericalMoments, sorry, I understood, that you after solution showed on the first image. The second one if far more simple. Will be added ASAP.

Comment: 1) ok, version 2 works for the current figure, lets call it Figure 1, in my paper. It works for Figure 2 too. However, the captions for Figures 3 and 4 became LEFT justified on its own, so i have to insert ``` \captionsetup{justification=centering}``` inside Figure 3 so that the caption of Figures 3 and 4 are center-justified. Why is this so?

2) Is it compulsory to use the figure environment? It ALWAYS split the text anyhow with the figure appearing at the wrong places, even with ```\begin{figure}[h]```

Comment: @SphericalMoments, this site is not a forum. If you have new problem, please ask new question, that other will be able to see, what is your problem and consequently may help you. In new (follow-up)  question please provide MWE, which reproduce your problem (from description in your comment this is not clear). BTW, I'm sure, that I solved problem reported in this answer and least you should consider to upvote and even accept it.

Comment: @SphericalMoments, see the second addendum to answer.

Comment: ok thank you Zarko

Answer (score 0):

For your second favourite output you can just add a starred caption coupled with raggedright like this:

```
\caption*{\raggedright Note: Really long note...}
```

Comment: The sides are not aligned, please see the last word of each line. I cant attach an image here